# Edit Drupal print

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have taken over a site that was uses a custom built theme in Drupal. I have minimal drupal knowledge, but I do know that home page is structured in the page.tpl.php file.

So when I open the file and navigate to the section I need to edit, I see a piece of code like this

```
<div id="deals">
<div class="container">
<?php print render($page['slider_deals']);?>
</div>
<br/><br/>
</div>
```

Now i am assuming, it is basically taking a block or a view and printing it there, but how do I get myself into the gritty part of 'slider_deals' to edit it, because I cant find it anywhere on the server or in the blocks or views in the backend console.

thank you, any help appreciated.

Comment: I believe drupal uses the M.V.C (Model.View.Controller) design pattern. So, the controller must be setting the content of `$page` variable and the template (view) is using it. Read up on this: https://drupal.org/project/controller

Comment: where do I find the template view

Answer (score 0):

This snippet basically renders a region named 'slider_deals'. A region is a container for blocks of content. Custom regions are defined in the theme's '.info' file. You can go to 'admin/structure/block' to manage which blocks get displayed in which region. The theme may also have a 'region.tpl.php' or 'region--slider-deals.tpl.php' file that renders that specific region, otherwise the rendering process falls back to the default 'region.tpl.php' file in 'modules/system'. You may also check in the theme's 'template.php' file for some `hook_preprocess_region()`, `hook_process_region()`, `hook_preprocess_region__slider_deals()` or `hook_process_region__slider_deals()` function that's called before rendering that region. 'preprocess' functions are called before 'process' functions in a two-stage process, just before rendering the corresponding template, thus allowing for last minute adjustments to the variables available in the template, as well as adding region-specific CSS and JS.